# Combining ArtifactArchiver and JunitResultsArchiver from different nodes using jenkins workflow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

How do I archive content from multiple nodes in a parallel build process?

I have a jenkins workflow job which builds win/lin in parallel.  When the job finishes, linux results overwirte the windows results.

How do I share or collect results from each node so I get both sets in my final product?

```
def branches = [:]

branches["Windows Build"] = {
  node('winx64&&slave')
  {
    // Do build
    ...
    // Collect      
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/build/test-results/*.xml', fingerprint: false])
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/build/reports/**,**/build/*.log', excludes: null])      }                
  }
}

branches["LinuxBuild"] = {
  node('linx64&&slave')
  {
    // Do build
    ...
    // Collect      
    step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/build/test-results/*.xml', fingerprint: false])
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/build/reports/**,**/build/*.log', excludes: null])      }                
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stash`/`unstash` steps with different names to retrieve the reports later and do whatever you want with them.

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    // do something
    stash includes: '**/build/reports/**,**/build/*.log', name: 'first'
}, secondBranch: {
    // do something else
    stash includes: '**/build/reports/**,**/build/*.log', name: 'second'
}

dir('dir1') {
    unstash 'first'
    // do whatever you want
}
archive 'dir1/*'

dir('dir2') {
    unstash 'second'
    // do whatever you want
}
archive 'dir2/*'
```

Comment: How expensive if stash?

Comment: Expensive? In what sense? It just creates a tar.gz containing all stashed files, store it in the build storage space and unstash does the reverse.

Comment: Time basically.  We've seen the archive plugin run slower than straight scp or rsync.  I guess, I'll try it and see what happens.  My data is pretty small

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I guess I could do the work in a Lin and Win directory and archive results from Win/**/... and Lin/**/... that's combine them and not overwrite but it seems a little kludgy.

Comment: That seems a reasonable idea. Otherwise, assuming that the files produced by each of the build steps have identical names, what would you expect to happen when archiving those same filenames twice?

Comment: Basically, I want to run tests on lin and win to ensure both platforms work.  So, I'm fine adding a level to ensure they both show up.